# Create Uniform Date across Varying Formats

Tags: r, date, time-series

I have a data set with about 53,000 rows, and one of the columns measures the date and time the observation was taken at. During the data collection, somehow, the format of the date switched from mm/dd/year to dd/mm/year, and this happened several times. However, I know the exact row where each of these errors occurred, so I was wondering if there is an efficient way to change them all to a single format (I want them in mm/dd/year since that is what most of the observations are in).

Here is an example of the problem I am talking about, going from dd/mm/year to mm/dd/year:

```
data.test = data.frame(Date = c("16/11/2017 8:45 AM", "16/11/2017 9:00 AM", 
"11/16/2017 9:15 AM", "11/16/2017 9:30 AM"), Observed = c(100, 23, 291, 30))
data.test

Date                Observed
16/11/2017 8:45 AM  100         
16/11/2017 9:00 AM  23          
11/16/2017 9:15 AM  291         
11/16/2017 9:30 AM  30
```

In my data set, the dates are characters, while the rest of the rows are numbers.

Comment: You have mentioned that you know rows where format has been switched. Does that info available as a flag based on which you know if date is switched?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but the person who collected the data gave the dates where this switch occurred and I found them in the data set. I could easily add another column that has some kind of dummy tag on the rows where this switch occurs.

Comment: There can be two approach. One in which you can use a flag (if available) to change dateformat and another approach could be to check if date is valid in mm-dd-yyyy then use it else use dd-mm-yyyy format. The `lubridate` provides a smart function to help in 2nd option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you know the location (presumably a range of row numbers) where the changes need to occur, but you didn't give those in your example, possibly because it was obvious. But it would not be obvious in cases where both mm and dd were less than 13.

```
data.test$Date <- as.character(data.test$Date) # prevent factor issues
dd_mm <- 1:2 # the rows to be changed
repl <-format( as.POSIXct( data.test$Date[dd_mm], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p"), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p" )
data.test$Date[dd_mm] <- repl
data.test
#-------------------------------------------
                 Date Observed
1 11/16/2017 08:45 AM      100
2 11/16/2017 09:00 AM       23
3  11/16/2017 9:15 AM      291
4  11/16/2017 9:30 AM       30
```

Comment: My apologies for not understanding your concern, so when both the month and the date are less than 13, it's not obvious what is the month and what is the date!

Answer (score 2):

I'll prefer to use `lubridate::parse_date_time` function in such case to handle heterogeneous format of date/time in same column

```
# Sample data.frame
# I have modified one date from sample used by OP to include both AM and PM 
data.test = data.frame(Date = c("16/11/2017 8:45 AM", "16/11/2017 9:00 PM", 
               "11/16/2017 9:15 AM", "11/16/2017 9:30 AM"), Observed = c(100, 23, 291, 30))

#modified column added in consistent format. 
library(lubridate)
data.test$modifeddatetime <- parse_date_time(data.test$Date, c("dmY HM p", "mdY HM p"))

#Change the modfieddatetime column back in character in desired format
data.test$modifeddatetime <- format(data.test$modifeddatetime, format="%m/%d/%Y %H-%M")


data.test
#                 Date Observed  modifeddatetime
# 1 16/11/2017 8:45 AM      100 11/16/2017 08-45
# 2 16/11/2017 9:00 PM       23 11/16/2017 21-00
# 3 11/16/2017 9:15 AM      291 11/16/2017 09-15
# 4 11/16/2017 9:30 AM       30 11/16/2017 09-30
```

Comment: Awesome! Just out of curiosity, is there any way to re-format the result (the last column) in such a way that it matches the first column? I'm really new to time series so I'm sure I wouldn't even need to do this to do analysis, but I would still like to know.

Comment: Yes. You can do that. I have just left the last column in Date/Time format. You can change it to desired format by converting it to character.

Comment: @AidenKenny modified solution to change format for modified column in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: I don't think `parse_date_time` could be smart enough to know whether "1/12/2019" is January 12  or December 1.

Comment: @42- That's why it takes preference for formats. Say in my case  I had provided `dmY` first and then `mdY`. That means if it cannot find valid date with `dmY` it will try `mdY`. All depends on how OP wants to use it.

Comment: Whisch was NOT how the OP describes the problem. He said there was a specific date when the format changed. Why he accepted this answer seems a mystery to me.

Comment: @42- Yes, it was not very clearly described but in answer to my queries (as part of question) OP replied stating that data was collected someone and by looking into data OP realized switch over. That is quite obvious that he would have noticed invalid date and to decide the format has been reverted.

Comment: @42- I'm not sure what you mean. Like I said I'm not sure how these commands work, and MKR's answer seemed like a good, simple solution. Going through several large chunks of the data, the re-formatted times match up exactly with the original dates, so there does not seem to be a problem.

Comment: Great. It appeared from your comments that there was a particular date after which the format switched, i.e that you knew which dates were in the desired format and which dates were not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting attempt at this. Assuming that your first observation is in the correct format, a bit of code is worked in to check for the most plausible date format based on what month the date is supposed to be in. How it deals with months changing I am not entirely sure yet.

The thought is as long as the first observation is correct it will carry forward in the right format until an ambiguous date is hit. At that point it is checked against a previous observation's month that is supposed to be right. If they match then the current ambiguous observation was predicted correctly, if not it selects the other format in place. Again when months switch and an ambiguous hits needs some work but I am too lazy (it's Friday)

```
data.test = data.frame(Date = c("9/8/2017 8:30 AM","8/9/2017 8:45 AM", "16/11/2017 9:00 AM", "11/16/2017 9:15 AM", "11/16/2017 9:30 AM"), Observed = c(100, 23, 291, 30, 45))

Date1<-
as.POSIXct(data.test$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p") # search for format1
Date2<-
as.POSIXct(data.test$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %p") # search for format2

# Replace data.test Date Column with Date1, leaving NAs
data.test$Date<-Date1


#Check most plausible date format.
for(i in 1:length(Date1)){
  if(is.na(Date1[i])==F  && is.na(Date2[i])==F && i!= 1){
    print(paste("row",i , "ambigious format"))
      if(month(Date1[i-1])==month(Date1[i])){
         print("Date Estimated from mm/dd/YYYY format based on previous")
      }else{
         Date1[i]<-Date2[i]
         print("Date Estimated from dd/mm/YYYY format based on previous")
}
}else{}
}



# Replace NAs in data.test with index from Date2, line up
data.test$Date[is.na(data.test$Date)] <- Date2[is.na(data.test$Date)]

> data.test
                 Date Observed
1 2017-09-08 08:30:00      100
2 2017-09-08 08:45:00       23
3 2017-11-16 09:00:00      291
4 2017-11-16 09:15:00       30
5 2017-11-16 09:30:00       45
```

Comment: Will not succeed if day and month are both less than 13. Need to know locations for accurate transposition targeting.

Comment: @42- Good observation, tried to address that problem with a very very strange workaround. It was fun at least lol.

Comment: You use of what might be called predictive parsing based on trailing results seems interesting.